# Why is $h_{\mu\nu}$ not a tensor in the perturbed Universe in cosmological perturbation theory?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, perturbation-theory

In the cosmological perturbation theory course per Hannu Kurki-Suonio (2022) : https://www.mv.helsinki.fi/home/hkurkisu/CosPer.pdf, there is a remark in the text page 5 that puzzles me. The text goes like this :

> We write the metric of the perturbed (around FRW(0)) universe as $g_{\mu\nu} = \bar{g}_{\mu\nu}+\delta g_{\mu\nu}=a^{2}\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}\right)$ where $h_{\mu\nu,}$ as well as $h_{\mu\nu,\rho}$ and $h_{\mu\nu,\rho\sigma}$ are assumed small. Since we are doing first-order perturbation theory, we shall drop from all equations all terms of order $O(h^2)$ or higher, and just write = to signify to first order in $h_{\mu\nu}$. **Here the perturbations $h_{\mu\nu}$ is not a tensor in the perturbed universe, neither is $\eta_{\mu\nu}$,** but we define: $h^{\mu}_{\nu} = \eta^{\mu\rho}h_{\rho\nu}$ and $h^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\rho}\eta^{\nu\rho}h_{\rho\sigma}$. One easily finds that the inverse metric of the perturbed spacetime is $g^{\mu\nu}=a^{-2}\left(\eta^{\mu\nu}-h^{\mu\nu}\right)$.

**QUESTION:** I'm not sure to understand why $h_{\mu\nu}$ is not a tensor. And if it's not a tensor, then what is it? What mathematical object are we manipulating? Is there any symbolic trickery to make everything work *as if* it were a tensor? Any clarification on what the author means would be really helpful.

Comment: Just apply the tensor transformation rule and disprove yourself that it's not a tensor. Just do it for unperturbed metric.

Comment: I don't think the claim is correct. The LHS is a tensor, so the RHS is also a tensor. Each term in the RHS is also a tensor, and you sum the tensorial terms to get a tensor.